# How to record desktop phone audio

Tags: audio, recording, phone, meetings

### My Scenario

I am often participating in LiveMeetings where a group of from 2 to 10 people are watching a share desktop - usually we are doing demonstrations/walktrhoughs through some application UX. Because these meetings occur across continents the participants are often in their homes using their home PCs.

The video sharing part is fine - no complaint.

The audio situation - typically we are dialed into a conference bridge with a normal telephone

So in this situation everyone is using LiveMeeting to see the video but using a normal phone to hear the conversation.

### What I Want

For archiving purposes and so that those not attending the meeting can watch/listen the meeting later I would like to record both the audio and video. (My recording application is Camtasia Studio.)

### My Question

What are my options to get phone audio into my computer so that I can use Camtasia Studio to record the audio and the video? What techniques have worked well for you?

### Notes

- My personal phone home is an ordinary desktop phone. Not a cell phone. Not a VOIP phone.
- My simple thought was that I just want an ordinary phone that *also* can be plugged into my PC's USB port so that I can use it as a kind of microphone
- I am willing to purchase a new phone - but not willing to switch over to VOIP for my phone service
- My OS: Windows 7
- Hardware info: My PC doesn't have a fax/modem card. I do have a great USB microphone (it can't pick up voices over the speakerphone very well however).

Comment: this guy is too organized :p (a girl maybe) you will get stupid answers anyway ...

Comment: and wait ... over continent regular phone calls ?... WOW

Comment: I hope my answer isn't too stupid ;)

Comment: you miss the most important things, what operating system you are running ? do your PC have a fax/modem card ? do you have a mic ?

Comment: Could you possibly make your section titles not all caps?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen devices at Radio Shack that allow you to record phone conversations--they just plug into the POTS handset and provide audio signal over a 1/4" stereo mini jack. You could plug that into the microphone or line in port of your sound card.

Don't forget you need permission to do this depending on where you live.

Answer (score 2):

You could try dialing in to the call using skype and recording the sound via your PC's Sound Recorder application.

Comment: To expound on this a touch, you (you being the OP) *don't* need (or even want) a microphone for this.  Dial in via your phone like usual.  Turn your Skype microphone off (or mute it).  Thus, the recording would get all voices at about the same level, as opposed to recording with a microphone pointed at your speakerphone (which would pick up your voice much louder than those on the phone).

Comment: Good idea. ...This would have come to me when I heard the audio, I hope. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's too bad you can't use a cellphone for this as bluetooth would be the solution to your problem.

[This website](http://www.altoedge.com/callrec/index.html) sells adapters that you connect somewhere along the phone line and they connect to your computer. You can then record the audio from the phone calls.

The third solution I can think of would be Google Voice. If you have it, or can somehow get an invite. Just use your Google Voice number during these conferences. That way you can still use the same phone and be able to record the whole conversation. I think you have to press "2" to start recording on Google Voice but you can easily look that up. Then when the conversation is over, all you have to do is go online to voice.google.com and the whole conversation will be right there, ready for you to download as an mp3 or whatever format. You can then easily combine the video and the audio.

Personally I would use bluetooth as it is the easiest and you can use it as an audio source on Camtasia. But if I didn't have a cellphone to use, I would definitely be taking advantage of Google Voice, especially since it's free.

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/36-010) would be a start- its a electromagnetic pickup designed specifically for this. Just add something to record it with ;)